# Вопрос про наследование в C#

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование

Господа, я запутался в трех соснах.

Я хочу

1. написать базовый класс, в котром есть метод - `void MyMethod()`
2. Использовать его в унаследованных классах, **не меняя их код** и вообще не создавая в классах - наследниках ничего похожего на `void MyMethod(){...}`

Но, похоже, я чего то не понимаю.

Если я напишу вот такую "заготовку"

```
    public interface IMyBase {
        void MyMethod();
    }
    
    public class MyBaseClass : IMyBase {
        public void MyMethod() {
            Debug.Print($"Hi from MyMethod()!");
        }
    }
```

и потом попробую в каком то другом классе унаследоваться от IMyBase - это приведёт к тому, что мне необходимо будет написать **реализацию** метода MyMethod(). А я хочу этого избежать :-)

То есть, если я пишу

```
    class WorkClass : IMyBase {

    }
```

то я получаю ошибку "метод не имплементирован". И от меня ожидается, что я напишу реализацию MyMethod() внутри класса WorkClass. А я хочу этого как раз избежать: написал в одном месте - и в коде WorkClass хотел бы просто вызвать по имени метод MyMethod, и чтобы при этом отработал код, который уже написан в MyBaseClass.

К сожалению, наследоваться от класса `MyBaseClass` в рабочем классе `WorkClass` я не могу: в настоящем коде у меня WorkClass уже наследуется от Form, а наследоваться от двух классов нельзя.

Вопрос не выглядит сложным, но, вероятно, я сразу что то стал делать не так.

Не могли бы вы мне дать совет?

Спасибо.

Comment: `WorkClass : IMyBaseMethod` ? - что это значит?  может надо так `WorkClass : MyBaseClass` ?

Comment: Наследуйте не от интерфейса, а от класса, где реализован этот метод.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский - да, Вы правы, исправил. Неаккуратно копипастил :-)

Comment: @ПавелЕриков - проблема в том, что я не могу наследоваться от двух классов - множественного наследования то нет.. А в рабочем классе у меня уже есть наследование от класса (на самом деле - от класса Form), от которого я не могу избавиться

Comment: Может я чего-то не понимаю, но что Вам мешает базовый класс унаследовать от `Form`, и плодить потом его наследников?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов "что Вам мешает базовый класс унаследовать от Form, и плодить потом его наследников" - очень интересно, сейчас попробую

Comment: Ещё вариант: использовать [агрегацию/композицию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Агрегирование_(программирование))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для .NET Framework для вашей задачи нет решения, ну если только унаследовать базовый класс от вашей новой абстракции. А вот для .NET Core 3.1/.NET 5 - есть.

Default Interface Methods

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IMyBase myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.MyMethod();
    }
}

class MyClass : MainBase, IMyBase
{
        
}

class MainBase
{

}

interface IMyBase
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hi from MyMethod()!");
    }
}
```

Кажется, работает

```
Hi from MyMethod()!
```

Единственное, что добавлю. Назначение DIM весьма специфичное, это скорее дял случаев, когда вам нужно расширить реализацию чего-то нерасширяемого типа базового класса, находящегося в какой-то сторонней библиотеке, но при этом у вас в коде уже большая куча классов, наследующих этот базовый класс, и вам не хочется вносить изменения в разных частях проекта. В нормальной же ситуации основная абстракция должна удовлетворять вашим требованиям и когда возникает модификации - модифицировать надо базовый класс, а не прикручивать что-либо сбоку.

Comment: aepot  - то есть, по простому говоря, в NET Core теперь можно в интерфейсах писать реализацию?

Comment: @S.H. есть нюансы, но в целом да.

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснения!

Comment: Мне друг подсказал еще один путь - extension method. По моему, очень свежая мысль

Comment: @S.H. ну не то чтобы свежая, но вопрос был про наследование. Но если ответ не в тему, я могу удалить.

Comment: Нет, ответ как раз очень в тему! Большое спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @S.H. тогда неплохо было бы, если бы он позеленел. А методы расширения можем обсудить в новом вопросе, если потребуется.

Comment: Да, конечно, я уже отметил, просто хотел нанисать микро проект для лучшего понимания сути

Answer (score 0):

Вы сделали базовый класс для наследников, соответственно надо от него и наследоваться:

```
class WorkClass : MyBaseClass {

}
```

В ином случае, логично, классу `WorkClass` неоткуда брать методы базового класса и нужно заново всё переопределять, т.к. вы подставили к нему интерфейс

Comment: `К сожалению, наследоваться от класса MyBaseClass в рабочем классе WorkClass я не могу`

Comment: @aepot - Спасибо, я добавил это уточнение в вопрос, уже после того, как увидел ответ. Сейчас  я читаю про  default interface methods, но не помешали бы и севеты, как сделать какой нибудь "хак" для обычного NET Framework.

Comment: @S.H. никак, можете только если базовый класс унаследовать от того что вам нужно.

Comment: Возможно, я сморожу чушь, но вообще: а Вам не кажется, что то, что я пытаюсь сделать, похоже на простую вещь из АОП? (аспектно - ориентированного П)?

Comment: @S.H. мне кажется, что у вас проблема с объектной моделью, в которую вы пытаетесь воткнуть костыль. :)